# how to identify table contain default and check constraints in sql?

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int  NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Age int  CHECK (Age>=18),
City varchar(255) DEFAULT 'Sandnes'
);
```

expected output is

```
----------------------------------------------------
fields               |     rule
-------------------------------------------
eid                     UNIQUE
Firstname               not null
Lastname                not null
age                     >18
city                   def=sandnes
---------------------------------------
```

how can i achieve this?

Comment: Columns, not fields... Which dbms are you using? Column constraints can be find in the information_schema.

Comment: What's the expected result is both NOT NULL and has a default value and a check constraint?

Comment: Your SQL client should display the information when you display the table's structure.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
exec sp_Columns Persons
```

and

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS ConstraintName, SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName, type_desc AS ConstraintType
FROM sys.objects
WHERE (type_desc LIKE '%CONSTRAINT') AND (OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) = 'Persons')
```

would suit your needs for MS SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work on Postgresql

```
select table1.table_name, table2.check_clause
from information_schema.table_constraints table1
join 
information_schema.check_constraints table2 
on table1.constraint_name=table2.constraint_name 
and 
table1.table_schema='<your schema name>';


 table_name | table_schema |     check_clause      
------------+--------------+-----------------------
 persons    | public       | firstname IS NOT NULL
 persons    | public       | id IS NOT NULL
 persons    | public       | lastname IS NOT NULL
 persons    | public       | ((age >= 18))
```

This is the expected result from the mentioned query..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution and its working fine.If you like the solution then please Vote.

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int  constraint UniqueType unique,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Age int constraint CheckType CHECK (Age>=18),
    City varchar(255) constraint DefaultType DEFAULT 'Sandnes')
```

Comment: This solution won't provide the output as requested

Comment: it is provide the output as requested